# Integration to paypal at local server

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, paypal-sandbox

In laravel 5.8 app I make integration to paypal with paypal/rest-api-sdk-php
and I make as :

```js
// Set up a payment
payment: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.create({

    return_urls : {
        return_url : 'http://local-votes.com/paypal_payment'
    },

    transactions: [{
        amount: {
        total: '0.01',
        currency: 'USD'
        }
    }]
    });
},
// Execute the payment
```

if return_urls is uncomment I got error in console :

```
VM19:1 POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ VM19:1
(anonymous) @ http.js:147
ZalgoPromise @ promise.js:41
request @ http.js:48
(anonymous) @ rest.js:243
_loop @ promise.js:162
_proto.dispatch @ promise.js:153
_proto.then @ promise.js:242
(anonymous) @ rest.js:225
_loop @ promise.js:162
_proto.dispatch @ promise.js:153
_proto.then @ promise.js:242
(anonymous) @ rest.js:217
_loop @ promise.js:162
_proto.dispatch @ promise.js:153
_proto.resolve @ promise.js:96
_loop @ promise.js:213
_proto.dispatch @ promise.js:153
_proto.resolve @ promise.js:96
(anonymous) @ promise.js:43
(anonymous) @ http.js:117
load (async)
(anonymous) @ http.js:78
ZalgoPromise @ promise.js:41
request @ http.js:48
Object.time @ rest.js:37
(anonymous) @ util.js:54
createPayment @ rest.js:209
(anonymous) @ serialize.js:34
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:401
(anonymous) @ serialize.js:33
(anonymous) @ types.js:68
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:401
_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) @ types.js:56
receiveMessage @ index.js:114
messageListener @ index.js:140
serialize.js:175 Uncaught Error: Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 400 error. Correlation id: 987ea0c89740a, 987ea0c89740a

{
    "name": "MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "message": "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "debug_id": "987ea0c89740a"
}

    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http.js:114)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_response] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:4206:27)
    at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
    at messageListener (index.js:140)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_response] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:4206:27)
    at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
    at messageListener (index.js:140)
    at serialize.js:175
    at serialize.js:212
    at util.js:140
    at util.js:102
    at util.js:116
    at replaceObject (util.js:138)
    at util.js:147
    at util.js:109
    at util.js:118
    at replaceObject (util.js:138)
```

where http://local-votes.com is my local host LAMP/Ubuntu 18

if to comment return_urls payment works ok but I do not have payment retun action.
If there is a way to work with it locally. Looking at some example code, looks like that is possible...

**MODIFIED :**

I uploaded the app under my hosting and hosting page is at 
https://www.mysite/test

I remade paypal payment function, as

```
                            payment: function(data, actions) {
                                return actions.payment.create({

                                    return_urls : {
                                        return_url : 'https://mysite/paypal_payment' 
                                    },

                                    transactions: [{
                                        amount: {
                                            total: '0.01',
                                            currency: 'USD'
                                        }
                                    }]
                                });
                            },
```

I expected as it is remote hosting under https it will work but anyway I got JS error :

```
VM19:1 POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ VM19:1
(anonymous) @ http.js:147
ZalgoPromise @ promise.js:41
request @ http.js:48
(anonymous) @ rest.js:243
_loop @ promise.js:162
_proto.dispatch @ promise.js:153
_proto.then @ promise.js:242
(anonymous) @ rest.js:225
_loop @ promise.js:162
_proto.dispatch @ promise.js:153
_proto.then @ promise.js:242
(anonymous) @ rest.js:217
_loop @ promise.js:162
_proto.dispatch @ promise.js:153
_proto.resolve @ promise.js:96
_loop @ promise.js:213
_proto.dispatch @ promise.js:153
_proto.resolve @ promise.js:96
(anonymous) @ promise.js:43
(anonymous) @ http.js:117
load (async)
(anonymous) @ http.js:78
ZalgoPromise @ promise.js:41
request @ http.js:48
Object.time @ rest.js:37
(anonymous) @ util.js:54
createPayment @ rest.js:209
(anonymous) @ serialize.js:34
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:401
(anonymous) @ serialize.js:33
(anonymous) @ types.js:68
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:401
_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) @ types.js:56
receiveMessage @ index.js:114
messageListener @ index.js:140
serialize.js:175 Uncaught Error: Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 400 error. Correlation id: 216d1df6b8ce, 216d1df6b8ce

{
    "name": "MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "message": "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "debug_id": "216d1df6b8ce"
}

    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http.js:114)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_response] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:4206:27)
    at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
    at messageListener (index.js:140)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_response] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:4206:27)
    at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
    at messageListener (index.js:140)
    at serialize.js:175
    at serialize.js:212
    at util.js:140
    at util.js:102
    at util.js:116
    at replaceObject (util.js:138)
    at util.js:147
    at util.js:109
    at util.js:118
    at replaceObject (util.js:138)



Why error and how to fix it ?
```

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED

Comment: is the local service accessible from the outside?

Comment: No, but in MODIFIED block I described the error after I apploaded the app on my Digital Ocean Server(ubuntu 18)

Answer (score 0):

Valid syntax was :

return actions.payment.create({

```
redirect_urls : {
    return_url : 'https://www.mysite/paypal_payment',
    cancel_url : 'https://www.mysite/paypal_payment_cancel'
},
```

that fixed the error